# SQL database errors, can't find parent key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, validation

I have a couple of errors in my sql database, I am trying to figure out why certain lines give me an error. I don't understand how some lines do not have the parent key when the rest do. I would appreciate any feedback.

```
DROP TABLE Ordering CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Customer CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Warehouse_Fullfillment CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Shipment_Preference CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Delivery CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE Returns CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; 

CREATE TABLE Ordering
( 
    customer_id     NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    invoice_id      VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    payment_total   NUMBER        NOT NULL,
    Order_Number    NUMBER        NOT NULL

);

CREATE TABLE Customer
(
  customer_id                     NUMBER          NOT NULL,
  customer_address1               VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_contact_last_name      VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_contact_first_name     VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_city                   VARCHAR2(50)    NOT NULL,
  customer_state                  VARCHAR2(50)         NOT NULL,
  customer_zip_code               VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
  customer_phone                  VARCHAR2(50),
  default_account_number          NUMBER          NOT NULL,
  Refund_Invoice_id      VARCHAR2 (50)  NOT NULL,
  Tracking_Code          Number         NOT NULL


);

CREATE TABLE Warehouse_Fullfillment
(
    Item_id                     Number          NOT NULL,
    Invoice_id                  VARCHAR2 (50)   NOT NULL,
    Item_Scanned                VARCHAR2 (50)   NOT NULL,               
    Order_Completion_Average    NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Damaged_Item_id             NUMBER          NOT NULL,
    Tracking_Code              Number        NOT NULL


);

CREATE TABLE Shipment_Preference 
(
    Status_id                  VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    Item_id                    Number NOT NULL,
    Shipment_type              Varchar2 (50) NOT NULL,
    invoice_id      VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Delivery
(
    return_id                  VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    Item_id                    Number NOT NULL,
    Customer_id                VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    date_of_desination         DATE        NOT NULL,
    Tracking_Code              Number        NOT NULL,
    Refund_Invoice_id        VARCHAR2 (50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Returns
( 
    Refund_Invoice_id        VARCHAR2 (50)  NOT NULL,
    Tracking_Code            Number         NOT NULL,
    return_id                  VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    customer_id     NUMBER          NOT NULL
);

 Alter Table Ordering 
   ADD Constraint Ordering_pk PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id); 

Alter TABLE Customer
ADD Constraint Customer_pk  PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id);

Alter Table Warehouse_Fullfillment
    ADD CONSTRAINT  Warehouse_Fullfillment_pk PRIMARY KEY( Item_id);

Alter Table Shipment_Preference 
ADD CONSTRAINT Shipment_Preference_pk Primary KEY (Status_id);

Alter Table Delivery
    ADD Constraint Delivery_pk PRIMARY KEY (Tracking_Code);

    Alter Table Returns
    ADD CONSTRAINT Returns_pk PRIMARY KEY (Refund_Invoice_id);



INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (1, 'Steve', 'Rodriquez','salt lake', '3652 CERMAK', 'Georgia', '60087', '2744808991', 48156, 252762, 206806541);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (2, 'Faye', 'Lawrence', 'memcity','59528 BALBO', 'Colorado', '23714', '4994745250', 25215, 9948784, 578883648);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (3, 'Fernando', 'Poole', 'lolcity','1693 RANDOLPH SUB', 'North Dakota', '67529', '4994745250', 35293, 9787943, 893371225);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (4, 'Raul', 'Weaver', 'dsad','8898 OHIO', 'Texas', '27709', '5026705519', 42542, 915335, 689553023);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (5, 'Neil', 'Maldonado','opdaddy', '74965 NORTH', 'Arizona', '94301', '1593029054', 57700, 8468823, 918257595);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (6, 'Patrick', 'Daniels','poking', '19 FOREMAN', 'Pennsylvania', '60656', '6433389900', 44919, 3593503, 118768693);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (7, 'Nina', 'James', 'fafe', '16 OAK', 'Utah', '78348', '2892496384', 5795, 575950, 575426221);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (8, 'Armando', 'Santiago','code', '1459 SOLIDARITY', 'Illinois', '36799', '2097829672', 57455, 1700328, 376418353);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (9, 'Pat', 'Bates', 'bath','99 BELLEVUE', 'Alaska', '35860', '1918078171', 82772, 4682474, 433556915);
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES (10, 'Pat', 'Bowman', 'bandlecity','8898 ERIE', 'South Carolina', '55474', '1034729258', 80151, 5235811, 462502003);


INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (1, 14364, '566', 820859);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (2, 43017, '662', 228408);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (3, 43317, '38', 754554);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (4, 44976, '516', 801963);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (5, 67918, '275', 493792);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (6, 75683, '395', 636601);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (7, 13120, '926', 893760);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (8, 37175, '481', 462599);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (9, 77809, '486', 88513);
INSERT INTO Ordering VALUES (10, 4078, '89', 668256);

INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (443863, 43432, 14364, 'Prime');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (272943, 52525, 43017, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (30951, 52355, 43317, 'Prime');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (235283, 64266, 44976, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (44934, 75753, 67918, 'Prime');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (588629, 54263, 75683, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (542942, 86573, 13120, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (960423, 56316, 37175, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (347727, 78526, 77809, 'Standard');
INSERT INTO Shipment_Preference  VALUES (993732, 97665, 4078, 'Prime');



 INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (43432,14364, 'Yes', 206806541, 0.63, 54117);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (52525, 43017, 'Yes', 578883648, 0.31, 81023);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (52355, 43317, 'Yes', 893371225, 0.4, 68759);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (64266, 44976, 'Yes', 689553023, 0.4, 47751);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (75753, 67918, 'Yes', 918257595, 0.3, 7507);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (54263, 75683, 'Yes', 118768693, 0.1, 23178);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (86573, 13120, 'Yes', 575426221, 0.71, 7126);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (56316, 37175, 'Yes', 376418353, 0.97, 85478);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (78526, 77809, 'Yes', 433556915, 0.02, 99696);
INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE_FULLFILLMENT VALUES (97665, 4078, 'Yes', 462502003, 0.85, 33137);



INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (535532, 1, 43432, TO_DATE(' 12/14/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 206806541, 252762);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (525545, 2, 52525, TO_DATE(' 12/14/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 578883648, 9948784);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (542526, 3, 52355, TO_DATE(' 12/14/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 893371225, 9787943);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (777777,4, 64266, TO_DATE(' 12/27/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 689553023, 9153351);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (888888,5, 75753, TO_DATE(' 12/18/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 918257595, 8468823);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (999999,6, 54263, TO_DATE(' 12/22/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 118768693, 3593503);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (111111,7, 86573, TO_DATE(' 12/20/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 575426221, 575950);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (101010,8, 56316, TO_DATE(' 12/22/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 376418353, 1700328);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (010101,9, 78526, TO_DATE(' 12/21/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 433556915, 4682474);
INSERT INTO Delivery  VALUES (524531,10, 97665, TO_DATE(' 12/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 462502003, 5235811);

INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (1, 535532, 2527621, 206806541);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (2, 525545, 9948784, 578883648);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (3, 542526, 9787943, 893371225);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (4, 777777, 9153351, 689553023);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (5, 888888, 8468823, 918257595);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (6, 999999, 3593503, 118768693);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (7, 111111, 575950, 575426221);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (8, 101010, 1700328, 376418353);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (9, 010101, 4682474, 433556915);
INSERT INTO Returns VALUES (10, 524531, 5235811, 462502003);

Alter Table Ordering
 ADD CONSTRAINT order_fk_Preference FOREIGN KEY (Customer_id) REFERENCES Customer (Customer_id);

 Alter Table Warehouse_Fullfillment
    ADD CONSTRAINT Warehouse_Fullfil_fk FOREIGN KEY (Invoice_id) REFERENCES Ordering (Invoice_id) ;

 Alter Table Shipment_Preference
 ADD CONSTRAINT Shipment_fk_Preference FOREIGN KEY (Item_id) REFERENCES Warehouse_Fullfillment (Item_id) ;


 Alter Table Shipment_Preference
  ADD CONSTRAINT Delivery_fk_Preference FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Ordering (Invoice_id);

 Alter Table Returns
 ADD CONSTRAINT Returns_fk_Preference Foreign Key (Tracking_code) REFERENCES Delivery(Tracking_code);

 Alter Table Returns
 ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_fk_Preference Foreign Key (Customer_id) References Customer (Customer_id);

 Alter Table Delivery 
 ADD CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_fk_o_preference Foreign key(Item_id) References Warehouse_Fullfillment (Item_id);

 Alter Table Delivery 
 Add constraint delivery_fk_12_pref Foreign Key (Refund_Invoice_id) References Returns (Refund_Invoice_id);

 Alter Table Customer
 Add Constraint customer_fk_12_pref Foreign Key (Tracking_code) References Delivery(Tracking_Code);

 Alter Table Warehouse_Fullfillment
 Add Constraint Warehouse_full_fk_35_pref Foreign Key (Tracking_Code) References Delivery (Tracking_Code);
```

> Error starting at line : 173 in command -  Alter Table
>   Shipment_Preference   ADD CONSTRAINT Delivery_fk_Preference FOREIGN
>   KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Ordering (Invoice_id) Error report -
>   ORA-02298: cannot validate (CIS255A28.DELIVERY_FK_PREFERENCE) - parent
>   keys not found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious
>
> Error starting at line : 176 in command -  Alter Table Returns  ADD
>   CONSTRAINT Returns_fk_Preference Foreign Key (Tracking_code)
>   REFERENCES Delivery(Tracking_code) Error report - ORA-02298: cannot
>   validate (CIS255A28.RETURNS_FK_PREFERENCE) - parent keys not found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious
>
> Error starting at line : 179 in command -  Alter Table Returns  ADD
>   CONSTRAINT Customer_fk_Preference Foreign Key (Customer_id) References
>   Customer (Customer_id) Error report - ORA-02298: cannot validate
>   (CIS255A28.CUSTOMER_FK_PREFERENCE) - parent keys not found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious
>
> Error starting at line : 182 in command -  Alter Table Delivery   ADD
>   CONSTRAINT DELIVERY_fk_o_preference Foreign key(Item_id) References
>   Warehouse_Fullfillment (Item_id) Error report - ORA-02298: cannot
>   validate (CIS255A28.DELIVERY_FK_O_PREFERENCE) - parent keys not found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious
>
> Error starting at line : 185 in command -  Alter Table Delivery   Add
>   constraint delivery_fk_12_pref Foreign Key (Refund_Invoice_id)
>   References Returns (Refund_Invoice_id) Error report - ORA-02298:
>   cannot validate (CIS255A28.DELIVERY_FK_12_PREF) - parent keys not
>   found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious
>
> Error starting at line : 191 in command -  Alter Table
>   Warehouse_Fullfillment  Add Constraint Warehouse_full_fk_35_pref
>   Foreign Key (Tracking_Code) References Delivery (Tracking_Code) Error
>   report - ORA-02298: cannot validate
>   (CIS255A28.WAREHOUSE_FULL_FK_35_PREF) - parent keys not found
>   02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
>   *Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
>              child records.
>   *Action:   Obvious

Comment: You are using Oracle, not sql server, not mysql, not any other database engine. Don't just pick random tags for your question.

Comment: It looks like your data types and values are different in your Foreign Key columns. For example, in your Ordering table, the INVOICE_ID is a NUMBER. The Shipment_Preference table's INVOICE_ID is a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

These error means that the data in parent and child tables are not in sync and the referential integrity is not being maintained.

For ex- if you noticed the first error in your example. This error means that you have Invoice_id in your Shipment_Preference table that are not present in the Ordering table. The foreign key can therefore not be applied.You have to either remove those orphaned records or UPDATE them if possible.